# The addition to Refaeinu

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, shemoneh-esrei, choleh-sick

In the artscroll siddur amongst others, there is a text to be added in to the bracha of refaeinu if one wants to daven for a specific choleh. The text seems to be rather standard (I.e. it is in some other siddurim too) - what is it's source (these words to be said in this place) and who made it up?

Comment: A quick search on Sefaria only shows results from the various Nusachos of the Siddur.

Comment: @DonielF It's in Heidenheim's siddur as well if we're talking about the same.

Comment: What is the text?  I don't have an artscroll siddur with me.

Comment: Probably better not to use a standardized text as per Aruch Hashulchan 119:2 and even better to leave any supplications until the end of shmoneh esrei as per chaye adam 24:19. Misleading attributions in Artscroll siddurim aside.

Answer (score 1):

There are several versions for the added Tfila on a specific choleh. For example in some sources it is important to mention the choleh's name, while in others mostly according to Kabbalic sources, and explicitely in the Zohar that one should not mention the name as it can even be counter productive to him, and they learn it from Moshe's tfila: "א-ל נא רפא נא לה".

The Misha Berura says that indeed it is not advisable mention the name, but only in front of him, and so when not in front of him one not only can but also should mention the name.

The Halacha is meforash in the Shulchan Aruch ([אורח חיים קיט א](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%98_%D7%90)).
See in length in the the Gmara and the Mefarshim - [Brachos, page 34](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%90).